# "??*" C++ escape sequence

Tags: c++, string, escaping

Note that the `*` in the title is meant to be a placeholder, in my case the culprit was `??[`.

I just came over C++ (also "C") escape sequences, formed by double question marks. What was this ever used for and why is it still there?

I have [ascii-85](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1924) encoded text where double question marks seldom occur and just spent an afternoon ripping the hair from my head while attempting to find a bug in the encoder / decoder, while it was simply the compiler playing tricks on me.

Comment: [Trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) are pretty useless nowadays and are not going to be in C++17. See the proposal: [Removing Trigraphs??!](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4086.html)

Comment: @chris That's an interesting and exciting development indeed!

Comment: And of course, C++ got them from C, where they are still (as far as I know) standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze you're right, I was confused since http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_Sequences_in_C does not explicitly mention `??`, while http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape does.

Comment: @JamesKanze: re the "still" in your comment, trigraphs are still standard in C++. AFAIK they will not be removed in C++14 either.

Comment: @Alf Of course they're still in C++.  No one said anything to the contrary.  But it was said that they weren't in C.

Comment: The trigraphs aren't escape sequences, they're trigraphs.  They may seem similar, but the standard keeps them separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C++ Standard

2.4 Trigraph sequences [lex.trigraph]

1 Before any other processing takes place, each occurrence of one of the following sequences of three characters (“trigraph sequences”) is replaced by the single character indicated in Table 1.
Table 1 — Trigraph sequences Trigraph Replacement Trigraph Replacement Trigraph Replacement

```
??= # ??( [ ??< {
??/ \ ??) ] ??> }
??’ ˆ ??! | ??- ~
```

However the symbol you showed `??*` is not a trigraph symbol. So it is difficult to say what it means.

It seems I have understood what it means. They are wild characters `?` and `*` Simply inside a string literal symbol `?` was doubled.:)

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf What does this mean?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Fixed that for you [filler] [filler]

Comment: @VladfromMoscow By `??*` i meant `??`, followed by a single character.

Comment: now it was re-deleted by a anonymous moderator who has a habit of deleting my short or disputed answers, using the nick Bill the Lizard. as i recall the last one he deleted had some 20 upvotes at the time. being hounded by an anonymous mod, jeez.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Do not worry. Be happy.:)